# IntelliJ IDEA: How to open pop-up "New in Current Directory"

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.2 (on I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.6), I follow video tutorial:
https://youtu.be/D3nnjmK1GwE?t=3m39s , but I don't know how to open pop-up "New in Current Directory".

[image]

Comment: What part of the video tutorial is confusing to you?

Comment: at 3 minute 39 second, add `persistence.xml` file from template.

Comment: Assume I cannot view the video. from your question and comment I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish. Is this a basic question about creating a project with the Intellij wizard on the OSX operating system?

Comment: `How to open pop-up “New in Current Directory”` is pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ has a universal shortcut to find all other [`Ctrl+Shift+A`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/navigating-to-action.html)

Using it you can find action `New...` that has a shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Insert`